# Передача данных в контроллер CakePHP(3.0)

Tags: php, cakephp

Правлю готовый проект - столкнулся с такой проблемой: как получить в функции контроллера id статьи, на которую перехожу.
Может как-то через ссылку, или как-то иначе. 
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ну видимо у вас должна быть настроена маршрутизация .. а в экшне будет входной параметр `$id` , типа `public function view($id)`  ........ http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html

Comment: Входной параметр - это понятно, но вот как именно настроить маршрутизацию, чтобы передавало  в View/master/card именно тот id на страницу которого я захожу?

Comment: Теоретически по умолчанию должно работать `mysite.ru/articles/view/1` или `mysite.ru/articles/1` вести на контроллер `Articles` экшн `view` с `id = 1` ..... в ином случае из ссылки сверху можно найти routing и почитать как это делается